# Want to create a single msi for .net application which will embedd third party tools

Tags: windows-installer

Want  to create a single msi for .net application which will embedd third party tools.

On executing this msi, it should copy all the files and then it should launch a third party tool's installer and wait for it to complete and then launch another third party tool's installer and again wait for it to finish and then finish the installation.

Is this possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Windows-Installer is an SDK, spec and installation service that's part of Windows. It's not really an authoring tool / suite.

You should take a look at tools such as WiX and InstallShield.  Both can create an MSI and both can chain MSI / EXE package together.  WiX calls this Burn and InstallShield calls this Suite installers.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for your reply.